# How to output coverage XML with nosetests?

Tags: python, code-coverage, cobertura, nosetests

I'm trying to output the coverage XML of my nosetests so they show up on Hudson.  The line I'm executing is:

```
nosetests --with-gae -v --all-modules --with-xunit --with-coverage
```

I see the coverage output in the console, but there's no xml file containing the coverage data.  How can I get it to output the coverage xml?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Once you've run the `nosetests` command, there will be a `.coverage` data file in the directory.  If you then run `coverage xml`, it will create a Cobertura-compatible XML file from the `.coverage` file.

Comment: With which package do you do that? I have installed coverage with pip and it complains about xml module not existing

Comment: @hithwen when python-coverage is installed you can execute it as `python -m coverage xml --include="mypackage*"`

Answer (score 8):

There is a plugin written for `nosetests` to do just this.

You just have to add `--with-xcoverage` once this package is installed.  It can be found at:

https://github.com/cmheisel/nose-xcover

Comment: Thanks.  Does this work better than the other answer?  The other way  tends to run coverage metrics through all the code on my PYTHONPATH, even if I tell it to just do everything in my 'tests' folder.

Comment: The option I gave is really the same but is done directly through a nose plugin.  Add '--cover-package=PACKAGE_NAME' option to limit what code is included in the coverage.